# Svg path each segment different color

Tags: javascript, svg, linear-gradients

I have a requirement, where I need to assign a different color to each path segments. I approached the problem by generating a dynamic data-driven `linear Gradient`as following

```js
//-----******PROOF OF CONCEPT*******---
const color = ["red", "green", "blue", "magenta"];
const svgns = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
const svgVan = document.querySelector('svg');

const lg = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'linearGradient');
lg.setAttribute('id', 'linear1');
lg.setAttribute('x1', '0%');
lg.setAttribute('y1', '0%');
lg.setAttribute('x2', '100%');
lg.setAttribute('y2', '0%');
svgVan.appendChild(lg);

color.forEach(
    (a, i) => {
        const stop1 = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'stop');
        stop1.setAttribute('offset', i / 4);
        stop1.setAttribute('stop-color', color[i]);
        lg.appendChild(stop1)

        const stop2 = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'stop');
        stop2.setAttribute('offset', (i + 1) / 4);
        stop2.setAttribute('stop-color', color[i]);
        lg.appendChild(stop2)
    }
)

const rect = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'rect')
rect.setAttribute('x', '100');
rect.setAttribute('y', '100');
rect.setAttribute('width', '600');
rect.setAttribute('height', '200');
rect.setAttribute('fill', 'url(#linear1)')
rect.setAttribute('stroke', 'black');
svgVan.appendChild(rect);

//-----******Application*******---
const array = [
    { x: 0, y: 80 },
    { x: 50, y: 20 },
    { x: 100, y: 50 },
    { x: 150, y: 30 },
    { x: 200, y: 40 },
    { x: 250, y: 90 },
    { x: 300, y: null },
    { x: 350, y: null },
    { x: 400, y: 20 },
    { x: 450, y: 70 },
    { x: 500, y: 60 },
];
var result = array.reduce((acc, curr, index) => acc + curr.y, 0);

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (i == 0) {
        array[i].z = array[i].y
    } else {
        array[i].z = array[i].y + array[i - 1].z
    }
}
array.forEach(
    (a) => {
        a.pct = a.z / result
    }
)
const lnr = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'linearGradient')
lnr.setAttribute('id', 'linearTest')
lnr.setAttribute('x1', '0%')
lnr.setAttribute('y1', '0%')
lnr.setAttribute('x2', '100%')
lnr.setAttribute('y2', '0%')
svgVan.appendChild(lnr);

const colorName = ["Blue", "Brown", "Crimson", "DarkCyan", "DarkMagenta", "DarkOliveGreen", "DarkOrchid", "DarkOrange", "DarkSalmon", "DarkSeaGreen", "DarkSlateBlue", "DarkSlateGrey"]

array.forEach(
    (a, i, r) => {
        const stop1 = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'stop');
        stop1.setAttribute('offset', (i == 0) ? 0 : r[i - 1].pct);
        stop1.setAttribute('stop-color', colorName[i]);        
        lnr.appendChild(stop1)
        const stop2 = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'stop');
        stop2.setAttribute('offset', a.pct);
        stop2.setAttribute('stop-color', colorName[i]);        
        lnr.appendChild(stop2);
    }
)

const pathVal = 'M' + array.filter((a) => a.y !== null).map((a, i) => a.x + ',' + a.y).join(' L')
const path = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'path');
path.setAttribute('d', pathVal);
path.setAttribute('fill', 'none')
path.setAttribute('stroke', 'url(#linearTest)')
path.setAttribute('stroke-width', '3px')
path.style.setProperty('transform', 'translate(100px, 400px)')
svgVan.appendChild(path);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>


<body>

    <div id="container" class="svg-container"></div>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1200 720">  

    </svg>
    <!--d3 script-->
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

However, the code is not assigning colors as desired to the path segments and I am having a hard time detecting where it is going wrong.

Path Segments are as following

[image: S1]

Comment: What should it look like?

Comment: If you do `array.filter((a,i) => a.y !== null && i<2)` or `array.filter((a,i) => a.y !== null && i<3...11)` you can see the segments and each segment needs a different color.

Comment: Please **show** that in your question.

Comment: Creating separate lines will be much easier

Answer (score 0):

Like Robert says; It is easier to draw the lines.

For a smoother effect you need to calc gradients, and calc the direction of the gradients depending on line slope.

```html
<svg-rainbow-line 
 points="0,80-50,20-100,50-150,30-200,40-250,90-300,0-350,0-400,20-450,70-500,60" 
 colors="red,orange,yellow,green,blue,purple"
 width="20"></svg-rainbow-line>

<script>
  customElements.define("svg-rainbow-line", class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      let xaxis = [], yaxis = []; // find viewPort boundaries
      let w = Number(this.getAttribute("width")||5); // stroke-width and padding
      let colors = (this.getAttribute("colors")||"red,yellow,blue").split(",");
      this.innerHTML = `<svg style="background:grey">${
          this
            .getAttribute("points")
            .split("-")
            .map(xy => xy.split(","))
            .map(([x2, y2,stopcolor="not implemented"], idx, arr) => {
              xaxis.push(~~x2); yaxis.push(~~y2);// force integers
              if (idx) {
                let [x1, y1,startcolor=colors.shift()] = arr[idx - 1]; // previous point
                // calc gradient here
                colors.push(startcolor);// cycle colors
                return `<line stroke="${startcolor}" stroke-width="${w}" 
                              stroke-linecap="round"
                              x1="${x1}" y1="${y1}" x2="${x2}" y2="${y2}"/>`;
              }
              return "";
            }).join("")}</svg>`;
      xaxis.sort((a, b) => a - b); yaxis.sort((a, b) => a - b); // sort by number!
      let vb = `${xaxis.at(0)-w} ${yaxis.at(0)-w} ${xaxis.at(-1)+w*2} ${yaxis.at(-1)+w*2}`;
      this.querySelector("svg").setAttribute("viewBox", vb);
    }
  })
</script>
```